# accidentally uninstalled xserver-xorg-core, and all other xserver packages

Tags: 14.04, xorg

I was trying to install xserver-xorg-video-dummy and said I needed to install xserver-xorg-core (which I assumed was already installed). So i typed

```
    sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-core
```

and rebooted and had some mouse problems and could've log in through the GUI. So I went into console and typed

```
    sudo apt-get purge -y xserver-xorg-core
```

and then after reboot I realized I messed up and couldn't do anything on the computer anymore. Thankfully, I have another Linux OS to operate on (and recovery for my original Linux Distro). Is there a solution through the console, or do I have to reinstall? The Distro is a spin off of Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling, somehow the network drivers were uninstalled too, which made it so i was unable to download the packages needed or repair.

Answer (score 0):

You can install **xserver-xorg-core** appropriate for your system by just typing :

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

If you are still having the problem please add the output of :

```
apt-cache madison xserver-common
```

Comment: Somehow, the network things were uninstalled too. Also, I'm unable to access TTY.